# Linking and inserting Facebook friends in Database

Tags: facebook, node.js, mongodb, facebook-graph-api, model

I'm developing an application that will need to know the friend's connection between registered users in my system.

So, importing those friends are one step of the process. However, I want to do it in the best way possible using MongoDB to reduce CPU and Query time.

I have basically 2 questions:

1) Should I keep the friendList record of each user inside it's own model (User), or with reference, in a new model (FacebookFriendship)?

```
// Nested (User Model)
{
    [...],
    facebookId: 12345,
    facebookFriends: [123456, 12313, 1241],
}

// Reference (FacebookFriendship Model)
{
    friendA: 12345,
    friendB: 12344,
    // Or maybe an array?
    friendship: [12345, 12344]
}
```

2) Other than the Model structure (That gives me a headache), I'm trying to figure out the proper way of importing things to the server.

Since I only need to know the friendship of those users that are already registered, I don't want to import all the friends of that facebook User.

In resume, what I want is to import those friendships, only if A and B side are both registered (The new user, and it's friend).

What I thought is something like this:

```
foreach Friend of newUser as friend:
   if FacebookUserExistsInServer(friend):
       createFriendShip(friend, newUser);
```

However, this approach requires a LOT of queries. Let's say 500 friends: 500 * 2 = 1000 queries for just one 'new' user. And I would still need to 'refresh' that data latter.

Is my approach a little too intensive, or ok for a normal application?

Thanks anyway!

Comment: FYI, since Graph 2.0, `me/friends` only returns friends who have installed the app, as opposed to all the user's friends.

Comment: That's nice! But creating a manyToMany model would be better than adding an array of users in a User field? @ChrisHoughton

Comment: Doesn't really matter, both would work. In our project we're doing the inline method because we care more about fast queries than 100% accuracy (in the case of unfriending).